# Angularjs ng-class $link

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I have a directive "D1" that needs to generate a nested directive "D2" which should use "D1" element width to generate svg content.

"D1" directive uses ng-class to dinamically determine dimensions

```
directive.template = "<div ng-class="col"></div>"
```

Variable col is defined in the directive controller scope as

```
$scope.col = "col-md-3" //Boostrap grid system
```

"D1" directive link function contains the code to generate the nested directive

```
var x = angular.element('<D2></D2>');
element.append(x);
$compile(x)(scope);
```

Difficulties starts from here.

Second directive "D2" should use "D1" element inner-width to generate contents with appropriate size but logging element.width() from "D2" linking function returns wrong dimensions ignoring the css style previously applied to "D1" the using ng-class.

I assume that the "D2" linking function runs before the "D1" ng-class has actually applied the class

Has anyone suggestion on how this issue should be approched?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/92ptvf9h/20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the `ng-class` on `D1` will defer applying the class to the next `$digest` cycle.

I couldn't think of a better solution than to also defer the second directive compilation as well.

If you are ok with it, you could defer the compilation with `$timeout` service like this:

```
post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
  console.log("First postLink width: " + iElement[0].clientWidth);

  $timeout(function () {
    var x = angular.element('<second></second>');
    iElement.append(x);
    $compile(x)(scope);
  }, 0);
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/7ba02otv/1/

Hope this helps.